# How to save matlab data in text with loop?

Tags: matlab

The result of my Matlab code is N cells arrays which are different in number of rows but the length of their columns are the same. I want to save them separately in text file.
ex:

```
A{1} = {0 0;0.0909 1;0.1818 2;0.2727 3;0.3636 4};
A{2} = {0 0;0.25 1;0.5 2;0.75 3;1 4};
A{3} = {0 0;0.1429 1;0.2857 2;0.4286 3};
```

The for-loop below does not work:

```
for i = 1:3   % N is 3
    dlmwrite('my_data.txt',A{i}, ';');
end
```

How can I have a loop to save them?

Comment: What does using no loop and just `dlmwrite('my_data.txt',A)`?

Comment: Error using dlmwrite (line 118)
The input cell array cannot be converted to a matrix.

Comment: Oh I just saw each cell contains a 2D matrix, what do you want the output to look like? Do you want 2 columns and then to stack `A{1}` above `A{2}` etc in the txt file?. Also can you not just create a numerical matrix that resembles your final txt file?

Comment: I want just the data of output to use in another function. so the appearance is not important.

Comment: Will each cell of your `A` always have the same number of columns (i.e. like *2* from your example)? If you then just stack them in your txt file how will you know how many rows each cell had? What you need to do with this data next is critical to your question, you can't leave that out unless you think about and specify that structure you want the data saved as in your txt file.

Comment: the columns are the same but rows not!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `-append` flag for the second and third calls to `dlmwrite()`.  Try this code:

```
dlmwrite('my_data.txt', A{1}, ';');

for i = 2:3   % N is 3
    dlmwrite('my_data.txt', A{i}, ';', '-append', 'roffset', 1);
end
```

Comment: there is an error: Error using dlmwrite (line 118)
delimeter is not a valid attribute or delimiter.
Delimiter must be a single character.'

Answer (score 0):

I can save all data with

```
save('data');
```

and then load each part I need with:

```
load('data.mat','A');
```